# How do I get the Bake console for CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am having trouble getting the Bake console.

I am on Windows running XAMPP.

I'm doing the [IBM CakePHP tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-cake2/section4.html).

Here is my directory:

```
C:\
  xampp
     htdocs
        ibm2 (a test project - orginally called cakephp)
          app
          cake
          vendors
          (etc)
```

It says to use Bake,

> cd into the /webroot/app directory and
>   launch the Cake Console:
>   ../cake/console/cake bake. You should
>   be presented with a screen that looks
>   like Figure 2.

So I write in my command prompt till I am at:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\ibm2\app>

Then I type

`../cake/console/cake bake`

but I get this error:

> '..' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program
>   or batch file.

What am I doing wrong? I use the Windows command prompt

Comment: http://kodegeek.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/how-to-bake-on-windows-xampp-environment/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Setting Up the CakePHP Console on Windows](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21Rt9HgITig) screencast.

Answer (score 0):

start the command prompt:

type `cd\` press enter and then `cd:/xampp/php` press enter
`php.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/cakeblog/lib/cake/console/cake.php` bake press enter

Answer (score 0):

This trick works for me :-

1. Go to shell folder which is in bin folder in cakephp 3.0.
2. Click on batch file.
3. After it open cmd and set path to your folder like `cd xampp/htdocs/test` and then enter bake commands

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 3.X bake and windows environment with wamp server you should have yet php environment variable active:

1. check with Powershell and type php-v if you see your version of php
2. Install cake php bake https://book.cakephp.org/bake/1/en/index.html
3. no need to install cakephp environmetn variable only go to the root folder on your project and type: PS C:\wamp64\www\yourcakephp3.x_project>bin/cake bake

Answer (score -1):

first check bake command in command prompt if it gives the out put not recognized as 
internal or external command than first add environment variable correctly than cake bake will
work correctly