# which is the environment variables route for cakephp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, configuration

I recently installed a cakephp with composer to learn about framework use, and trying the [bookmarks tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html), but I get stucked in the checking your installation where you have to open the command line AKA cmd, and writing `bin\cake`.

It replies back: the system cannot find the path specified.

I've seen some information about how to set up the path variables but I'm guessing it's for version 2+ because apparently the cakephp 3 doesn't have a LIB folder like such:
`YOUR_CAKE_DIR/lib/Cake/Console/`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks
best regards!

***************UPDATE**********************

well, I've finally fixed the problem, the path I used for the cakePHP 3 instalation was:

c:\xampp\htdocs\caketest\bin

so I assume that If you aren't using xampp, it should point at the end to: cakeinstallation\bin...

my problem was that I always typed bin\cake but actually all I had to do was type only:

cake

you can read more information in [here](http://nurelm.com/running-cakephp-command-line-tools-in-windows/)

Comment: The above update should be an answer to the question.

Comment: Take a look to this answer:[baking cakephp 3.X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65048310/12492646)

Comment: In this post you could find how bake in cakephp 3.X version
[Cake php 3.x bake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65048310/12492646)

Answer (score 1):

bin\cake shouldn't require any special path settings other than being in the correct directory. However, you should make sure that php-cli is on your system's PATH. Depending on how you install PHP it could be in any number of places, but if `php -v` doesn't output the version of PHP you installed, you'll need to find where your installer put PHP and then setup the PATH environment variable.

Comment: well, the php version I have is PHP Version 5.6.3, in fact, when I open the cake folder on the localhost to check it says that everything is fine. and I also put in the environment variables: c:\xampp\htdocs\caketest\bin\cake;C:\xampp\php\ and still it doesn't work, it says: the system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 0):

With your example, AFAI remember the working directory they were executing cake binary was the parent of "bin" folder, in your case "caketest". I am talking without trying it (I dont have an environment close) you should use:

`c:\xampp\htdocs\caketest> "bin/cake"`

Watch the **quotes**. I think they are the main reason of that "the system cannot find the path specified."

I am supossing you are under windows (I saw xampp written in your post) and probably the xampp installation has already added the php folder in the PATH environment variable.